# SuperUser tag for Adobe Photoshop

Tags: discussion, tags

I am looking for a little guidance from the community.

Earlier today, I answered a question on SuperUser. After looking at the other Adobe-related tags already existing on SuperUser, I retagged the asker's original tag of [photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) with [adobe-photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop). (The other tags were [adobe-reader](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-reader), [adobe-illustrator](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator), etc).

I just visited the question and saw that another user retagged the question back to [photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop).

There are currently 27 questions tagged just [photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) - should these be retagged to [adobe-photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) to fall in line with the other Adobe products? Or should the [photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) tag remain alone?

Comment: Closing, as no longer relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Retagging [photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) to [adobe-photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) seems over the top for the application.

When you talk with art students bleeding from the nose about the program they're using, they usually just curse the high cost of [photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) and not with the adobe prefix.

Unless another company comes along infringing on the name, it should be okay to go with just [photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop).

Not sure about its use as a verb though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think "adobe-" is necessary in the tag. There's really no other "photoshop." You can request a tag-merge though if you see the divide getting larger and larger between the two.

Comment: That was my thought, but I was also wondering about using "photoshop" as a verb, as many people do - It may not make sense, but I could photoshop a picture in Paint.Net. If this were the case, I would think having a "adobe-photoshop" would be good for referring to the actual product.

Comment: @Jared Harley: i think the appropriate tag for something about photoshopping should be "photoshopping", which would be different from the "photoshop" tag.  they are two related but distinct things.  photoshopping doesn't necessarily have anything to do with photoshop, and photoshop doesn't necessarily have anything to do with photoshopping.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't likely to be a popular opinion but what the hell. Too much rep on Meta can be a bad thing.

I say, keep both [photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) *and* [adobe-photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop).

[photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) has become a verb much in the way that Google or RollerBlade has. Its somewhat detached from the program itself at this point. You can 'Shop something in Gimp for example. For questions about image manipulation, vector drawing, etc. the [photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) tag may be appropriate, even if the question asker is using Paint Shop Pro, Corel Draw or the Gimp.

The [adobe-photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) tag could be used for complications with learning that program and most likely should be treated in the same way we treat versions of Windows or Visual Studio (i.e. [adobe-photoshop-cs4](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop-cs4), [adobe-photoshop-mx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop-mx) , [adobe-photoshop-cs2](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop-cs2), etc.).

Comment: +1 because I wanted to write something similar. "to photoshop" has become a verb meaning "photo manipulation" in many circles, although we should then think if we want to allow usage like that on SU.

Comment: Any tag for "the act of photoshopping" (sorry, Adobe IP lawyers) needs to be unambiguously about that specific subject.  Having both [adobe-photoshop] and [photoshop] begs for trouble and confusion.